# How Can i Select the Last 5 records in a databese

Tags: c#

i use this query to select the last record in the table 'Vente'

```
Vente ven = model.Vente.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

And now i want to modify this query to get the last 5 records
How can i do

Comment: entity framework? link to sql? nhibernate?

Comment: and have a look at `.Take` and `.Skip`

Comment: as Daniel said `model.Vente.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(5).ToList()`

Comment: the order is not always guaranteed coming out of a relational db.

Comment: @DanielA.White interesting - can you elaborate or add a reference link explaining your last note

Comment: @Stavm well in this case it is but if you just do `select *` its not

Answer (score -1):

You can use .Take(this IQueryable source, int count) extensions. After using `OrderByDescending`, you can add simply `Take` operation. Your source is not matter after this point.

Note: (answer assume ID is incremental value. If it is not (like guid) OrderByDescending does not return what you want)

```
IQueryable<Vente> vens = model.Vente.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(5);
```

Comment: Just a question, but why the downvote ? Seemed quite reasonable an approach.

Comment: @BlackLight taking comments of others, and posting them as your own answer is not something to be up-voted for. specially when we posted comments because we assume its his framework in use, and not sure of it, until he states otherwise.

Comment: Ah... didn't spot that. Although, as they were both around the same time, could have been just a co-incidence ? Very valid point though, and I agree the sentiment.

Comment: In question, user use `OrderByDesending`. This function return `OrderedIEnumarable` object. `Take`extensions methods take `IEnumarable` object as a parameter and `OrderedIEnumarable`is castable `IEnumarable`. In this circumtance, simply answer question like write `Take`operation after than `OrderBy`operation. Another issue is that, `OrderBy` and `Take` operations are in the same library and both of them support same frameworks, so again I do not  have to wory which framework is used by user. All above situation leads to give an answer like that, not suggest or add comment about question.